# Delete Arraylist data before adding

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, arraylist

**My Code**

```
 private void addOnlineData(final String item) {
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {

                final String message = dataSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString();
                final String time = dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue().toString();
                final String from = dataSnapshot.child("From").getValue().toString();
                final String seen = dataSnapshot.child("Seen").getValue().toString();

                LastSeen lastSeeen = new LastSeen();
                long lastTime = Long.parseLong(time);
                final String lastSeenTime = lastSeeen.lastSeen(lastTime, getActivity());

                mDatabaseReference.child("UserData").child(item).child("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

//CODE GIVEN BELOW WAS HERE

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The things I've tried

**1**

```
                        Log.d("HHHHH2222", String.valueOf(mChats.size()));
  mChats.remove(new HomeScreenChatsHelper(name, message, lastSeenTime, from, seen));
                        Log.d("HHHHH2222", String.valueOf(mChats.size()));
  mChats.add(new HomeScreenChatsHelper(name, message, lastSeenTime, from, seen));
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**2**

```
                        Log.d("HHHHH2222", String.valueOf(mChats.size()));
                        mChats.clear();
                        mChats.add(new HomeScreenChatsHelper(name, message, lastSeenTime, from, seen));
                        Log.d("HHHHH2222", String.valueOf(mChats.size()));
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My activity just gets user data from firebase and presently it has 2 childs
if I change the data of an user the data in the arraylist should be deleted and added again to the changed data

Suppose the value of User A is X
        the value of User B is Y

It shows that way in activity and if I change the value of User A to P from X
I want the activity to show the new data which is P

**But in the methods that I tried.**

*1st One Im getting 3 values which is A = X, B = Y and A = P

As you can see new data is added but existing data isn't removed*

*In the 2nd Method the activity just keeps refreshing with only ne data which is A = P*

**When new data is added I want to delete the old data and show the new one without repetition**

The methods I tried, The code was inside the onDataChange

Helper Class

```
public class HomeScreenChatsHelper {

private String Name;
private String LastMessage;
private String LastMessageTime;
private String From;
private String Seen;

public HomeScreenChatsHelper(){
}

public HomeScreenChatsHelper(String name, String lastMessage, String lastMessageTime, String from, String seen) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.LastMessage = lastMessage;
    this.LastMessageTime = lastMessageTime;
    this.From = from;
    this.Seen = seen;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return LastMessage;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    LastMessage = message;
}

public String getTime() {
    return LastMessageTime;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    LastMessageTime = time;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return From;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    From = from;
}

public String getSeen() {
    return Seen;
}

public void setSeen(String seen) {
    Seen = seen;
}
```

}

Comment: Does your `HomeScreenChatsHelper` class implement the `.equals` and `.hashCode` methods? Those are required for the List's `.contains` method and `.remove` methods (among others) for it to know which object to remove.

Comment: No it doesn't implement any of those... @KevinCruijssen

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your first method tries to remove A = P and then adding A = P.

If you manage how to change your object in mChats.remove(object) to A = X. It should work.

Just to cover everything mChats.clear(); makes mChats empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HomeScreenChatsHelper` most likely lacks a `hashCode()` and `equals()` method, which is required for the `List#remove(Object)` (or `List#contains(Object)` and similar methods) to work, so it knows which `HomeScreenChatsHelper` in the list is the same as the one you want to remove.

Most IDEs will have a way to auto generate these two methods. In the IntelliJ IDE you press Alt + Insert (or right click > Generate...)

[image: IntelliJ Generate Menu]

Then click "equals() and hashCode()"

Or in Eclipse you right click somewhere on the source and select:
"Source" > "Generate hashCode() and equals()..."

[image: Eclipse Right Click Menu]

Either way, it will produce something like the following for your class:

```
public class HomeScreenChatsHelper {

    private String name;
    private String lastMessage;
    private String lastMessageTime;
    private String from;
    private String seen;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((from == null) ? 0 : from.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((lastMessage == null) ? 0 : lastMessage.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((lastMessageTime == null) ? 0 : lastMessageTime.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((seen == null) ? 0 : seen.hashCode());
      return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj)
        return true;
      if (obj == null)
        return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
      HomeScreenChatsHelper other = (HomeScreenChatsHelper) obj;
      if (from == null) {
        if (other.from != null)
          return false;
      } else if (!from.equals(other.from))
        return false;
      if (lastMessage == null) {
        if (other.lastMessage != null)
          return false;
      } else if (!lastMessage.equals(other.lastMessage))
        return false;
      if (lastMessageTime == null) {
        if (other.lastMessageTime != null)
          return false;
      } else if (!lastMessageTime.equals(other.lastMessageTime))
        return false;
      if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
          return false;
      } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
      if (seen == null) {
        if (other.seen != null)
          return false;
      } else if (!seen.equals(other.seen))
        return false;
      return true;
    }

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

With this, your **option 1** should work as intended, by deleting the `HomeScreenChatsHelper` with the old data, and adding the `HomeScreenChatsHelper` with the new data (in your current code of option 1 you are both deleting and adding the new data instead).

Comment: mChats.remove(new HomeScreenChatsHelper(name, message, lastSeenTime, from, seen));

Comment: but still its not getting removed... I added a log statement below to check size and it remains same

Comment: @MaiseeMiller But isn't `new HomeScreenChatsHelper(name, message, lastSeenTime, from, seen)` the one you want to add? The one you want to remove has a different `name` and other properties, won't it? You mention you have a User A with values X and a User B with values Y, and you want to remove user A with values X, and add user A with values P. Shouldn't the remove and add then not have different inputs? Values `X` to remove and values `P` to add? Or am I misunderstanding what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is keep a separate HashMap of `user_names.put(user_code, user_name)` and update the name in that HashMap `user_names.replace(user_code, user_name)`

Note:only add a user when it does not exist otherwise update.

pass HashMap user_key in your statement

```
mChats.add(new HomeScreenChatsHelper(user_names.user_key, message, lastSeenTime, from, seen));
```

When you want to display name of the user fetch it from user_names HashMap.

```
user_names.get(user_key)
```